# What does 在留資格別 mean?

Tags: words

I couldnt find any entry on jisho, and also googling and wikipedia didnt help.
From: https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20180127/k10011304581000.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

在留資格 is [this](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9C%A8%E7%95%99%E8%B3%87%E6%A0%BC). 別 means "Categorized by ...".